# VueJS: Building for production...Killed

Tags: javascript, vue.js, deployment, centos

When running `npm run build` or `vue-cli-service build`. I get the message "Building for production...Killed" after about 30 seconds. The build works for me locally (MacOS), but when I try to deploy it on a DigitalOcean Server (CentOS 8.2 x64) it fails to build. Any ideas?

Comment: there could be a lot of things causing this, i.e. memory on the server too low, node and npm version not compatible. It could be easier for others to help if there is a log of the build command

Comment: Thanks. I got it working it turned out to the swap memory size

Answer (score 4):

I found my the solution to my problem by increase the swap memory on my server. I solved it using these steps...

Run `sudo fallocate -l 4G /swapfile; ls -lh /swapfile; sudo chmod 600 /swapfile; sudo mkswap /swapfile; sudo swapon /swapfile; sudo swapon -s; free -m;`

Then run `sudo vim /etc/fstab` then add this to the bottom of the file -> `/swapfile none swap sw 0 0`

Comment: Oh! you saved me, thanks you

Comment: Yet DO recommends not using swap files on their servers. See https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-space-on-debian-10  "...Due to this consideration, we do not recommend enabling swap on DigitalOcean or any other provider that uses SSD storage. Doing so can impact the reliability of the underlying hardware..."

Comment: @Bryan I already did this before reading your comment. Do you know how to reverse it? Also, do you know another way to solve the problem?

Comment: @alkadelik. I increased the droplet's memory.